# What is the difference between \s and \h in terms of regular expression? Are they same?

Tags: regex

R,Python
I tried \h and \s and they both behave the same way meaning they select white spaces in a string...i want to select a line which completely blank

Comment: `\h` will match only horizontal whitespaces, thus e.g. no linebreak.

Comment: \h is horizontal white space. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html